# What Data Format is this?

Tags: formatting

Does anyone know what format this data is?

```
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
```

thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoded XML:

```
<SlideOutline>
  <SIP uid="5373A691-6D9F-57A7-B93B-F6B98CB400C9" id="F8500C77-9D46-A829-A401-F6B98CA0157E" uvID="a6036582-237b-4349-9cd9-735bf5fd0156"/>
  <SIP uid="FE8C89E0-DC1C-41EA-3AC7-0433BD4D21EB" id="84264E6F-8FCE-21D4-D010-F4C503BD7653" uvID="cf56df18-8e5d-4e45-bd21-050c6c94f2ea"/>
  <SIP uid="C6540E6A-4343-D4D8-A0B6-0433CECC2089" id="21EF5EA2-F0D3-E898-1817-F4C8D3EB4DE7" uvID="4464f607-83e0-498c-8abe-b45b5409f008"/>
</SlideOutline>
```

Comment: You can decode it with:
  byte[] ba = Convert.FromBase64String(str);

Answer (score 3):

Most probably pure Base-64.  It doesn't have line breaks in it, unlike Base-64 encoding used in emails.  You can find the details in [RFC 3548](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3548.html).